# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

My flutter app working fine but after I try to get SHA-1 key it unfortunetly it show following error :
*The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':location' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20*

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
```

My *kotlin gradle plugin* are updated

Answer (score 8):

In Android Studio use:

> Ctrl + Shift + F

Find all your plugins' `ext.kotlin_version` version.

[Find all ext.kotlin_version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whD4Y.png)

and make sure they're version 1.5.20 and higher.

Comment: Are you recommending to change the bild.gradle of 3rd party libraries to fix this ? If so, that solutions doesn't seem sustainable. `flutter clean` will delete all those manual changes.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps to solve:

1. Go to android studio.
2. Open project folder over the android icon.
3. Open flutter plugins.
4. open on_audio_quary file/Location file.
5. Open build.gradle file.
6. Than change the (ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20')

I added an image to help with understanding.

[image: screenshot for clarity]

Comment: I helped with the markdown for formatting. Assuming that your phrasing (which initially I had problems to parse) means that you are providing an answer, with a clarifying screenshot in case the textual description is unclear. Good work actually, unless I have largely misunderstood your post. Please review.

Comment: This solution NOT worked for me. I have set `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'` higher & latest version but still not working. Any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20'` not solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio:

1. Ctrl + Shift + F
2. search version name like - 1.3.50 -- I found this version in scope while searching
3. replace version with 1.5.20

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur because of 3rd party package that has an older gradle version.

Try to upgrade your packages:

```
flutter pub outdated
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Then you may face some changed in methods names in your project, adjust them and run the project :)