# Another Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle, wakelock

I found many discussions regarding this error, but I am not able to fix it.
I have a flutter project, building to Android and iOS. I just upgraded from 3.7.10 to 3.19.0 and are upgrading the pubspec libraries:

```json
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1
  provider: ^6.0.5
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
  polygon: ^0.1.0
  http: ^1.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.14
  intl: ^0.18.1
  collection: ^1.17.2
  add_2_calendar: ^3.0.1
  text_scroll: ^0.2.0
  ory_client: ^1.2.11
  webview_flutter: ^4.7.0
  get_it: ^7.6.7
  injectable: ^2.3.2
  dio: ^5.3.3
  one_of: ^1.5.0
  flutter_web_auth: ^0.5.0
  flutter_libphonenumber: ^2.1.5
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.14.11

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  injectable_generator: ^2.4.1
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
```

The build.gradle:

```json
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
                project.android {
                    if (namespace == null) {
                        namespace project.group
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I try to run or build the project I get the following error:

```json
* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':wakelock' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I suppose the problem relies in the iOS dependency wakelock, but if I take a look at its gradle I find `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'`

If in Android Studio I do `CTRL + SHIFT + F` and look for all `ext.kotlin_version`s, all are greater than 1.3.50.

I have already done `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73857333/the-android-gradle-plugin-supports-only-kotlin-gradle-plugin-version-1-5-20-and) did not help, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74329121/android-gradle-plugin-supports-only-kotlin-gradle-plugin-version-1-5-20-and-high) neither.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wos that `wakelock` was included as a dipendency because of another library present in the `pubspec.yaml`, the min requirement was a very old version which run with an old gradle version. In order to fix the problem I needed to add a newer version, even if I dont use it directly. Adding `wakelock: ^0.6.2` fixed my problem.